# Foreign Keys error

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, alter

I have been altering all my tables to define the FK and am getting an error when attempting this table studentRsp .

```
ALTER TABLE StudentRsp
add CONSTRAINT fk_rspDate
  FOREIGN KEY (rspDate)
  REFERENCES LecturerRsp(rspDate);
```

Am getting the error

> Error Message: There are no primary or candidate keys in the
>   referenced table 'LecturerRsp' that match the referencing column list
>   in the foreign key 'fk_rspDate'. Could not create constraint. see
>   previous errors.

The rspDate is defined as a primary key in LecturerRsp

Comment: You said that rspDate is defined as "a primary key," which doesn't quite make sense, since each table has at most 1 primary key. I think you mean to say that it is defined as part of the primary key, which get right to the heart of the problem.

Comment: I have multiple Primary keys on my table

Comment: If your primary key consists of multiple columns, any foreign key must reference **all** those columns in the PK - not just one of those

Answer (score 0):

Look for rows in your StudentRsp that have a field that doesn't exist in your LecturerRsp table.  In other words the constraint requires all fields in the foriegn key column to match a field in the primary key column and there is a key in the StudentRsp that doesn't exist in the LecturerRsp

Example:

```
LecturerRsp         StudentRsp
 pk_Col1             fk_Col1
  1                     1
  2                     2
  3                     4
  4                     5 ***
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear acutally - just read it...

> *There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table
>   'LecturerRsp' that match the referencing column list in the foreign
>   key 'fk_rspDate'.*

You want to reference your table `LecturerRsp` and its column `rspDate` - but this message clearly tells you: `rspDate` is not the primary key on that table, nor is it part of a unique index/constraint.

Either of those two is a requirement for your to be able to reference that column from a foreign key.

To fix this:

- either change the primary key on `LecturerRsp` to be on column `rspDate`
- or (if possible) create a unique index on that column

If you cannot do either of these two things, then you **cannot reference** that column from a foreign key.